# Difference between oracle call and execute in context of error throwing

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I have some procedure written in Oracle. Unfortunately I can't show its code. Somewhere inside it is select where execution crashed because of absence of required data. It looks like this

```
select value into l_value
        from config
       where code = upper(p_code);
```

So when I call this procedure like this (in SqlDeveloper)

```
execute some_package.some_procedure('CODE');
```

it throws

```
Error report -
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", line 111
ORA-06512: at "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", line 111
ORA-06512: at line 1
01403. 00000 -  "no data found"
*Cause:    No data was found from the objects.
*Action:   There was no data from the objects which may be due to end of fetch.
```

But when I call it like this

```
call some_package.some_procedure('CODE');
```

it crashes at the same place (as I can suggest from the result, stored in DB), but it does no throw an exception.

```
some_package.some_procedure('CODE') succeeded.
```

What happens? And why there is such difference?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`NO_DATA_FOUND` exception behavior is special. It is handled by default in SQL context but not in PL/SQL. In SQL no data found is not considered as an error, it happens all the time that there is no data that meets certain condition.

`CALL` is SQL command whereas `EXEC` is a shortcut for `BEGIN <code> END;` which is PL/SQL.